# Why does a working torch setup suddenly raise a numpy.core.multiarray import error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I had a working setup for a project of mine which uses pytorch. It suddenly started raising a `numpy.core.multiarray` import error even though everything ran just fine before that.
I will paste the according code parts below.

```
python3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 12 2021, 09:26:00) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "*blurred out*/.pyenv/versions/deeplearning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>>>
```

```
python3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 12 2021, 09:26:00) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy.core.multiarray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in numpy.random._bit_generator
  File "*blurred out*/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/secrets.py", line 20, in <module>
    from random import SystemRandom
ImportError: cannot import name 'SystemRandom' from 'random' (*blurred out*)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "*blurred out*/.pyenv/versions/maml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "*blurred out*/.pyenv/versions/maml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "*blurred out*/.pyenv/versions/maml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "_bit_generator.pyx", line 43, in init numpy.random._bit_generator
ImportError: cannot import name SystemRandom
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple. I created a file called `random.py` which numpy then tried to import as the system random which of course wouldn't work. Renaming / Deleting this file fixes the error.

If you run into the same error as I did try to debug it with the second part which is `import numpy.core.multiarray`. If it raises any obvious errors try to fix those. Otherwise the reinstall / version change as proposed in the internet might help.